# Special Linear group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $F$ be any field.

Verify the group axioms for the special linear group $SL_n(F)$ whose elements are $n$ x $n$ invertible matricies with entries in $F$ and the product is matrix multiplication.

\begin{equation}
SL_n(F) = [A \in GL_n(F) : \text{det} A =1].
\end{equation}

I have managed to verify the 3 axioms for $GL_n(F)$ but I am unsure how to extend this to $SL_n(F)$ . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\det (AB)=\det (A)\det (B)$.

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ will get you one of the three axioms.

Comment: Closure and inversion should follow from some familiar facts from linear algebra - that det ($AB$) = det ($A$) det $(B)$, and that the inverse of a matrix of determinant 1 has determinant 1. It is already known that matrix multiplication is associative.

Comment: How to prove the identity axiom?

Answer (score 2):

We can "extend" this to $SL_n(F)$ as follows. After having seen that $GL_n(F)$ is a group we show that 
$$
\det\colon GL_n(F)\rightarrow F^{\times}
$$
is a group homomorphism with kernel $SL_n(F)$. As a kernel, $SL_n(F)$ then is a normal subgroup of $GL_n(F)$, hence in particular a group. Of course, this amounts to showing the group axioms, because the fact that $\det$ is a group homomorphism means that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ (see the hints).